# New view controller showing up modally instead of full screen on iPads

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

As I want to have more control over actions of when someone could press a button for going to another view controller, I tried to step away from the navigation controller system.

At the moment, as I'm still just a starter in Xcode I'm struggling with opening a view controller and closing it.

I tried to open it with this code:

```
@IBAction func didTapGame(){
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Game_VC") as! Game_ViewController
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

and on the iPhones it seemed legit, but on the iPad it appeared modally as a screen on top of the homescreen of the app and too small so you could just tap it away on the side.

How do you properly present a view controller in code in storyboard and how do you close it again with a backbutton as I tried the backbutton the same way, but it just added a new homescreen on top of everything which isn't desirable of course, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answers without more context, but if you have a UINavigationController you can try this:

```
self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController: vc, animated: true)
```